# How to remove the line on the road created by Google Direction Service API?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm making a project now that uses Google Direction Service API to get the Estimated Time of Arrival, and display a line on the two places on Google Maps.

I have a marker on GMaps which when clicked, it will trigger a Direction Service Query getting the marker's position as origin and a static value of place's name as destination.

The problem is every time I click the marker it creates new line. I want it to be replaced by the new line of the new origin and destination.

I could not find any way to remove the line first before calling the Direction Service API again.

The setDirection() method is called when marker is clicked.

```
function setDirection ( marker ) {
  start = marker.getPosition( );
  //start=localStorage.getItem("positionLatLng");
  end = 'Liceo de Cagayan university';
  directionService();

}

function directionService( ) {
   var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
   var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer(); 
   directionsDisplay.setMap( map );
   directionsDisplay.setOptions( { suppressMarkers: true } );
   directionsDisplay.setPanel( document.getElementById('panel') );

   var request = {
   origin:start, 
   destination:end,
   travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
   optimizeWaypoints: true
 };

   directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
     if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
       directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
       var route = response.routes[0];

        var summaryPanel = document.getElementById('panel');
        summaryPanel.innerHTML = '';
        // For each route, display summary information.
        for (var i = 0; i < route.legs.length; i++) {
        var routeSegment = i + 1;
        eta=route.legs[i].duration.text;
        }
     } else {
      console.log( "Error: " + status );
     }
   });
```

Please help guys. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your creating a new direction service evrytime and not clearing the old one.  So everytime your calling setDorection it will create a new service and keep adding them to the map.

Declare the servervice and rendeder outside of the function requesting the route then everytime you click the marker clear the directions before making a new route request.

Put this code in its own function and only call it once:

```
   // Declare these outside of the function so you can access tem     
   // same as the map but assign them here
   var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
   var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer(); 

   directionsDisplay.setMap( map );
   directionsDisplay.setOptions( { suppressMarkers: true } );
   directionsDisplay.setPanel( document.getElementById('panel') );
```

**EDIT**

Here is an update based on your comment:

Step 1 - declare your Service and renderer

```
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
var directionsDisplay = null; // notice this is null for now.
```

Step 2 - Get your start and end

```
function setDirection ( marker ) 
{
    var start = marker.getPosition( );
    var end = 'Liceo de Cagayan university';

    // pass the start and end into the function
    directionService(start, end);
}
```

Step 3 - Make the request - notice where I clear the old directions display
and where i create a new one AFTER the request comes back with a response.

```
function directionService(start, end)
{
    // Clear the old directions display if it exists
    // before making a new request
    //*** this is where you are going wrong ***
    if (directionsDisplay != null)
    {
        directionsDisplay.setMap(null);
        directionsDisplay = null;
    }

    var request =
    {
        origin : start,
        destination : end,
        travelMode : google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
        optimizeWaypoints : true
    };

    // Make the request
    directionsService.route(request, function(response, status)
    {
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK)
        {
            // get your results
            var route = response.routes[0];

            // Once the request comes back with the results
            // now create a new directions display and set the directions and map
            directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
            directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);          
            directionsDisplay.setOptions(
            {
                 suppressMarkers: true,
                 map:map
            });


            // do the rest
            var summaryPanel = document.getElementById('panel');
            summaryPanel.innerHTML = '';
            // For each route, display summary information.
            for (var i = 0; i < route.legs.length; i++)
            {
                var routeSegment = i + 1;
                eta = route.legs[i].duration.text;
            }

            // set your panel
            directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById('panel'));

        }
        else
        {
            console.log("Error: " + status);
        }
    });
}
```

EDIT:

Here is a JSFiddle to assist you: http://jsfiddle.net/loanburger/qqm7n899/

Comment: Hello there. I really appreciate your help. Thank you very much. But I can't figure it out. What code do i need to put in a function?

`myFunction(){
directionsDisplay.setMap( map );
   directionsDisplay.setOptions( { suppressMarkers: true } );
   directionsDisplay.setPanel( document.getElementById('panel') );
}
`

and the following codes

`var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
   var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer(); `

will be placed out side the function?

Comment: Sir thank you very much! It has helped me in solving my problem. Your first answer gave me clues in solving it.

Answer (score 0):

I thanked Sir @loanburger for his answer that gave me clues on solving this problem. Aside from his answer above, here is my code that also runs and suits what I need. I just did what he suggested that i should have another function to set the result. THANKS everyone and enjoy!

```
var start , end;
function setDirection ( marker ) {
  start = marker.getPosition( );
  end = 'Liceo de Cagayan university';
  directionService();
  settingTheResult( );

}
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer(); 
function settingTheResult( ){
    directionsDisplay.setMap( map );
    directionsDisplay.setOptions( { suppressMarkers: true } );
    directionsDisplay.setPanel( document.getElementById('panel') );   
}
function directionService( ) {
   var request = {
   origin:start, 
   destination:end,
   travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
   optimizeWaypoints: true
 };

   directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
     if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
        directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
        var route = response.routes[0];
        var summaryPanel = document.getElementById('panel');
        summaryPanel.innerHTML = '';
        // For each route, display summary information.
        for (var i = 0; i < route.legs.length; i++) {
        var routeSegment = i + 1;
        eta=route.legs[i].duration.text;
        }
     } else {
      console.log( "Error: " + status );
     }
   });
```